# Saving output while tasking is running in Azure Batch (using python SDK)

Tags: python, azure-batch, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I want to save the output of a task while it is running.
I was able to save the output only after the task completion.

I found in the C# azure sdk documentation that it has a SaveTrackedAsync function that enables to track a file and save it to a storage. Does the python SDK has a similar feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Batch Python SDK does not have a built in similar feature. You should be able to create a storage BlobClient specified to create an append blob type.